# Can I mock a system with custom properties?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We're using the Destinations service to configure connections to different kinds of systems. As part of this, we are using the "Additional Properties" section to add non-standard properties, such as `my.custom.property=123`.

We have successfully used the SAP Cloud SDK's `MockUtil` to write Spring integration tests that use the files `systems.yml` and `credentials.yml` as source for test systems.

However, we couldn't find a way to create an entry there that would provide a test system with a custom property like `my.custom.property=123`.

The `erp` section accepts only the properties known for ERP systems, such as `sapClient`. The general `systems` section accepts only the absolute basic properties name, type, uri, and proxy. Adding an unknown property in either section results in a runtime error because the mock utils are unable to parse the unknown property into the data classes with fixed structure.

Is there another way to mock a Destination that would allow us to include non-standard properties?

For example, the `DestinationAccessorMocker` looks promising, as it seems to enable setting up custom implementations of the `Destination` interface, but we couldn't figure out how to employ it.

Answer (score 6):

Found an option that works.

```
MockUtil mockUtil = new MockUtil();
MockDestination destination = MockDestination
  .builder("my-service", URI.create("http://localhost:1234/"))
  .property("my.custom.property", "123")
  .build();
mockUtil.mockDestination(destination);
```

Maybe somebody can confirm that this is an intended way to do this?

Comment: Yes you are exactly right, this is also the approach I would have recommended. So I think you can mark your answer as correct :)